# Script for edit PC name

Tags: windows-10, script

I know that the PowerShell command for rename a PC is

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "LAPTOP-*******" -Force
```

I need a script that replace "DESKTOP" with "LAPTOP" and leave the next 8 character in the PC Name.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Ok, I think that I'm getting closer to a solution:

```
$cmdOutput = $env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "DESKTOP", "LAPTOP" | Out-String
Rename-Computer -NewName "$cmdOutput" -Force
```

But I get this error about not allowed characters (it's not true):

```
Rename-Computer : Il computer 'DESKTOP-RJL7RM8' con il nuovo nome 'LAPTOP-RJL7RM8
' verrà ignorato perché il nuovo nome non è valido. Il formato del nuovo nome di computer immesso non è corretto. I
nomi standard possono contenere lettere (a-z, A-Z), numeri (0-9) e segni meno (-), ma non sono consentiti spazi o
punti (.). Il nome non può essere costituito esclusivamente da cifre e la lunghezza non può essere maggiore di 63
caratteri.
In D:\RenamePC\RenamePC.ps1:2 car:1
+ Rename-Computer -NewName "$cmdOutput" -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (LAPTOP-RJL7RM8
:String) [Rename-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidNewName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand
```

RE-EDIT:

I think that the error is a new line after the new name.
I tried to add `-NoNewLine` at the end of the first line, but Powershell answer:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NoNewLine'.
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? [SU] is not a code-writing service; you'll need to identify a specific problem and then we can help you solve it.

Comment: I asked here because I've no idea of how to carry out it. I spent a day searching a solution with no result, probably because I haven't much experience in scripting and my search query are very generic…
I really want to learn, but was not my intention to offend someone or breaking rules.
I can delete my question if necessary

Comment: Why are you piping the result of the `-replace` to `Out-String`?

Comment: I believed that without it the variable would have used the command itself, not its result, but I just tried without piping and it works. Thanks, it's simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to "Trim" the blanks.  Here's the code.

```
$cmdOutput = ($env:COMPUTERNAME -replace "DESKTOP", "LAPTOP" | Out-String).Trim()
```

Comment: Awesome! Now it works flawlessly!
Many many tanks!